# Strange error when an array is assigned to a row of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['tom', 10], ['harry', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
Y = [10, 100]
df.loc[0:(df.shape[0] - 1), ['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]]] =Y
```

With this I am getting below error:

[image]

I am using Python version `3.7.4` and pandas version `0.25.1`

I am expecting below result

[image]

Could you please help me what went wrong with my above code?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have added information on what I was expecting

Comment: Your example works for me as expected (pandas 1.1.5, Python 3.6.10). And you can use `df[[f'a{x}' for x in [10, 100]]] =Y` without the `.loc`.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: @DYZ getting the same error with `df[[f'a{x}' for x in [10, 100]]] =Y`. Is there any other way with backward compatibility? I am using Python version `3.7.4`

Comment: I asked you a question.

Comment: @DYZ  pandas version `0.25.1`

Comment: Bizarre. 0.25.1 is very old but still newer than 0.13. Perhaps you can add columns one by one?

Answer (score 0):

In last line of your code

```py
df.loc[0:(df.shape[0] - 1), ['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]]] =Y
```

you are querying for columns `a10, a100` by
`['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]]`.

These columns are not available in `df` as only `['Name', 'Age']` are present.

Comment: I am not querying. I am trying to add new columns with code `['a'+str(x) for x in [10, 100]]` which will hold the information from `Y`

Comment: @Bogaso `df.loc[rows, column] = value`, you are trying to *index* into `df` with `columns == ["a10", "a100"]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "The .loc/.ix/[] operations can perform enlargement when setting a non-existant key for that axis." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement

Comment: @DYZ yes, I was just reading your comment above. Seems like it is "New in version 0.13." so maybe outdated version for OP?

Comment: It may be outdated, not sure. Is there any other way with backward compatibility?